# Swift AppDelegate Struct usage

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a global variable I can use across my app. I figured out I can put stuff in the AppDelegate class and it will be accessible everywhere, if you know a better way please let me know.

When I try to make a struct I am running in to problems. My Code:

```
struct category {
    let one: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    let two: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    let three: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    let four: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
}
```

and when I try to access that in any class I get the error

```
Instance member 'one' cannot be used on type 'category'
```

I also tried using:

```
struct category {
    let one: UInt32 {
        get {
           return 0x1 << 1
        } 
    }
}
```

and That didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's nothing special about the App Delegate. You can make a global variable anywhere as long as it's in its own scope (not contained inside anything).

Second, the error you're getting is because the `let`s you create are instance variables, meaning you need an instance of category. So you could say

```
let myCategory = category()
let one = myCategory.one
```

But this probably isn't what you want if you want a global constant. Make the `let`s `static` if you don't want to have to create an instance of the object:

```
struct category {
    static let one: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
    static let two: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
    static let three: UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
    static let four: UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
}

let one = category.one
```

Third, you should capitalize struct names (`Category`) and read up on the [Swift language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) where all of this is explained.